# groupby not working on Pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to do a Group_by on an pandas Series and then do a rank on it. Weirdly this worked in previous versions of pandas but has now stopped working since we upgraded our version of pandas to 0.14.0

here is an example

The series

```
    i1 = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [u'A', u'B'], [u'Spar', u'PnP', 'Checkers', 'Woolworths']],
          labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                  [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]],
          names=[u'respondent', u'survey', u'brand'])
s1 = pd.Series.from_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2], index = i1, name='usage')
s1 
respondent  survey  brand     
0           A       Spar          1
                    PnP           2
                    Checkers      3
                    Woolworths    4
            B       Spar          2
                    PnP           3
                    Checkers      4
                    Woolworths    1
1           A       Spar          3
                    PnP           4
                    Checkers      2
                    Woolworths    1
            B       Spar          4
                    PnP           1
                    Checkers      2
                    Woolworths    3
2           A       Spar          1
                    PnP           2
                    Checkers      3
                    Woolworths    4
            B       Spar          3
                    PnP           2
                    Checkers      1
                    Woolworths    4
3           A       Spar          2
                    PnP           3
                    Checkers      4
                    Woolworths    1
            B       Spar          1
                    PnP           4
                    Checkers      3
                    Woolworths    2
Name: usage, dtype: int64
```

When I try and do a group by as follows

```
s1.groupby(['respondent']).rank()
```

I get the following error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-14bf5be195e8> in <module>()
----> 1 s1.groupby(['respondent']).mean()

/Users/donovanthomson/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
   2727         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   2728         return groupby(self, by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
-> 2729                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
   2730 
   2731     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, normalize=False):

/Users/donovanthomson/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in groupby(obj, by, **kwds)
   1098         raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))
   1099 
-> 1100     return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
   1101 
   1102 

/Users/donovanthomson/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
    384         if grouper is None:
    385             grouper, exclusions, obj = _get_grouper(obj, keys, axis=axis,
--> 386                                                     level=level, sort=sort)
    387 
    388         self.obj = obj

/Users/donovanthomson/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort)
   1978             exclusions.append(gpr)
   1979             name = gpr
-> 1980             gpr = obj[gpr]
   1981 
   1982         if isinstance(gpr, Categorical) and len(gpr) != len(obj):

/Users/donovanthomson/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    477     def __getitem__(self, key):
    478         try:
--> 479             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    480 
    481             if not np.isscalar(result):

/Users/donovanthomson/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   2554                     raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   2555                 else:
-> 2556                     raise e1
   2557             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
   2558                 raise e1

KeyError: 'respondent'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to groupby your index level not a column that doesn't exist:

```
In [218]:
s1.groupby(level=0).rank()

Out[218]:
respondent  survey  brand     
0           A       Spar          1.5
                    PnP           3.5
                    Checkers      5.5
                    Woolworths    7.5
            B       Spar          3.5
                    PnP           5.5
                    Checkers      7.5
                    Woolworths    1.5
1           A       Spar          5.5
                    PnP           7.5
                    Checkers      3.5
                    Woolworths    1.5
            B       Spar          7.5
                    PnP           1.5
                    Checkers      3.5
                    Woolworths    5.5
2           A       Spar          1.5
                    PnP           3.5
                    Checkers      5.5
                    Woolworths    7.5
            B       Spar          5.5
                    PnP           3.5
                    Checkers      1.5
                    Woolworths    7.5
3           A       Spar          3.5
                    PnP           5.5
                    Checkers      7.5
                    Woolworths    1.5
            B       Spar          1.5
                    PnP           7.5
                    Checkers      5.5
                    Woolworths    3.5
dtype: float64
```

You can also use `s1.groupby(level='respondent').rank()` if you prefer

technically I think it shouldn't have worked in previous versions as it's semantically different grouping on index levels vs. columns

Comment: Thanks a lot for the speedy feedback ! For bonus points do you know if this did change recently ? I couldn't find anything in the change logs of pandas

Comment: I can't find anything specific in [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/whatsnew.html)